# How to create/update user_id in sessions table?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

How to update/create `user_id` in `sessions` table in Laravel 5.2.

So I store sessions in a Database - here is the migration:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

Whenever user logs in with my own authentication I create a session like so:

```
$request->session()->put('user', ['name' =>' John', 'user_id' => 1 ]);
```

This doesn't set `user_id` in my `sessions` table, but I would like the `user_id` in my `sessions` table to correspond to my logged in user's `id`. So I can track in `sessions` table users by their `user_id`.

How can I set `user_id` in my `sessions` table?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

To use database for session. First you must in the .env file set

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

Then you should know that your saving is in the payload, not that it saves user_id that you tell. The user_id is the Auth::user()->id, not what you save

**EDIT:**

If you want to change the way laravel gets Auth::user(), you may decide to implement a UserProvider (very difficult)

Comment: Yes I'm using DB for my sessions all is good, but I need to set custom user_id - not using Laravel's Auth... That's the problem